# Problem involving Real Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $C$ and $E$ are distinct $n \times n$ real matrices. If
$C^3 = E^3$ and $C^2 E = E^2 C,$ I want to figure out if $C^3 + E^2$ could be
invertible.

I am imagining that the best way to start off a problem like this is to simply
develop some conjectures. We can see that $C$ and $E$ are not necessarily
invertible, although I would imagine that if they were invertible, there may
be some properties that could help us with our equalities. For now, let us
assume that $C$ and $E$ are invertible (we'll relax this assumption later).

We would like to simplify $C^3 + E^2 = E^3 + E^2$ into a product of $C$ and
$E$ matrices, as then we can use their invertibility to ensure the invertibility
of $C^3 + E^2.$ We see that
$C^2 E = E^2 C \implies E^2 = C^2 E C^{-1}
\implies E^3 = C^2 E C^{-1}.$
I'd like to know if the below factorization is legal:
$$E^3 + E^2 = E C^2 E C^{-1} + C^2 E C^{-1} = (E + I)(C^2 E C^{-1}),$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. If this is legal, then all I would need to do
is find the properties of $E$ that would ensure $E+I$ is invertible. Any
suggestions on what to assume about $E$ to ensure this statement?

Comment: $E+I$ is invertible if and only if $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $E$.

Comment: Do you mean $ E^2 = C^2EC^{-1} \implies E^3 = EC^2EC^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement that $E+I$ is invertible bears no relation with the equality $C^2E=E^2C$. Indeed, from $C^3=E^3$,
$$
C^3+E^2=E^3+E^2=E^2(I+E). 
$$
This shows that $E^3+E^2$ is invertible if and only if both $E$ and $I+E$ are invertible. This means that $E^3+E^2$ is invertible precisely when $0$ and $-1$ are not eigenvalues of $E$.